# Using negative lookahead multiple times (or matching multiple characters with ^)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to do something like this:

```
/<script[^>]*>(?!<\/script>)*<\/script>/g
```

to match all scripts tag in a html string using javascript.

I know this won't work but i can't seem to find any other solutions.
The script-tag can either use the src attribute and close it self right after (`<script src="..." type="text/javascript"></script>`) or can contain the code within the script-tag (`<script type="text/javascript">...</script>`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close

```
/<script[^>]*>(?:(?!<\/script>).)*<\/script>/g
```

You must have something to eat the actual script body. That's what the `.` does here.

The look-ahead check must occur before every character, so it is wrapped in an extra (non-capturing) group. To capture the script source code in group 1, just add another set of parens around the `(?:...)` like @AlanMoore pointed out in the comments.

Comment: @Denis: Wasn't part of the requirement. Wouldn't hurt, though. From what I can see the OP is proficient enough to do this himself. :)

Comment: Correction: to capture the script source code, you would need to add another set of parens: `((?:(?!<\/script>).)*)`.  If you merely removed the `?:` from the existing group - `((?!<\/script>).)*` - you would end up capturing only the last *character* of the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
/<script[^>]*>.*?<\/script>/g
```

I don't see a reason for a negative look ahead. `.*?` is a lazy match so that it only matches till the next closing tag and not till the last one.